# is there cryptography algorithm space /input invariant?

Tags: cryptography

i m searching a algoritm for cryptography that produces always the same result for the same input and if in the input at position k there is XXXXXX,
in the output at position k there is always the field YYYYYY

Comment: Substitutions like AB-YZ-> BC-ZA, or "randomized" version A->Q, B->A, C->M, ... won't work? It's a weak cipher, though.

Comment: Such behaviour would weaken the cipher considerably.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Also see [deterministic format preserving encryption](https://www.google.com/search?q=deterministic+format+preserving+encryption). Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] or [security.se] are much better suited for handling such a question.

Comment: @jww is correct; you seem to be looking for some sort of deterministic format-preserving encryption, or maybe even something as simple as a substitution cipher.  But be warned, these are extremely vulnerable to frequency analysis.

Comment: Collecting  these opinions and hearing about no real secure solution in the actual theories  i think  i can skip over :) Anyway also this answer is very usefull. Sometimes no is more usefull than yes :)